# How to set Phone number with extension in iPhone Webapp?

Tags: html, ios, phone-number, phone-call

IN a webapp, if I put down a number as below:

```
<a href="tel:888-123-4567">call now</a>
```

iPhone will turn that link into an instant call function when click. 
However, if I have extension, e.g. 1-888-123-4567 ext 009  (just one level of extension).
what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually use a "pause" which is represented by ',' character.

```
<a href="tel:888-123-4567,009">call now</a>
```

This will dial the number, wait for the call to be connected and then dial the extension number.

Answer (score 0):

isn't an extension just a dial through number? so just use

```
<a href="tel:+18881234567009">call now</a>
```